# How should I mount the main partition when using "set partitions manually"?

Tags: mount, system-installation

While installing Lubuntu, I choose to set partitions manually. Now I'm facing an *"I don't know what to do"* moment.

For the main partition, I choose an *Ext4* file system but I don't know what to select for:

1. *Mount point* and
2. *Bootable flag*

As this will be the primary partition (where OS will be) I choose `/` as mount point and set ON the bootable flag (default is off).

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, you're on the right way. Just proceed the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

When setting the partitions manually there's little you need to do. You just need to set the size of the partition and what mount point you will have on each one. So, only set the root `/` mount point in your preferred partition, and the others mount points (/home, /boot, /var?) wherever you like. GRUB installation will take care of the boot flag in your partitions.